# jQuery UI Datepicker - How to have equal width of calendar and input field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**PROBLEM:** Initially width of calendar is set to be the same as of input field. However, once clicked on prev/next buttons (to change month), calendar width will reseted.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:** Using onChangeMonthYear function like this one, but its not working:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function() {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').outerWidth($('#thedate').outerWidth());
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
  <input id="thedate" type="text" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){

    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($('#thedate').outerWidth());
            },0);
        },
    });

});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/63x6t1d5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cafp58w6/8/

```
$(function(){
  $('#thedate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($('#thedate').outerWidth());
      }, 0);
    },
  });

  $('div.ui-datepicker').on('click',function(){
    $(this).outerWidth($('#thedate').outerWidth());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have the options :

```
changeYear: true,
changeMonth: true,
```

To make month and year as select input
So in addition to **beforeShow**, you need to use **onChangeMonthYear** otherwise when we select another year or month the width of calendar go back to the original one so here is my complete code

```
$( "#date_naissance" ).datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    yearRange: '1900:2050',
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        console.log("before");
        console.log(input);
        console.log(inst);
        setTimeout(function(){
            inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($(input).outerWidth());
        },0);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear : function (year, month, inst) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($(inst.input).outerWidth());
        },0);
    }
});
```