# Modifying Datepicker Close Animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When the date picker is open I want it to be the [same width as the associated input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471165/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-have-equal-width-of-calendar-and-input-field). When the date picker closes, I want it to close in a single motion. But as soon I select a to and from date, no longer does the datepicker close in a single motion.

I have tried ideas such as `inst.dpDiv.outerWidth(0)` and partially modifying the code found here https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css. But nothing has worked and now I feel like I am going round round in circles.

I was going to include a JSFiddle but because of discrepancies between running the code in Sublime and JSFiddle I decided not to. And because the problem is only on the screen for a second (or less) I cannot take a screenshot.

I have tried hard to only include relevant code below. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Update** - Thank you Ghassen Louhaichi for the edit, in the below snippet you can see the stuttering I am talking about.

```js
$(function() {
    from = $('#arrivalDate').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($('#arrivalDate').outerWidth());
            }, 0);
        },
        onClose: function() {
            if ($('#arrivalDate').datepicker('getDate') != null) {
                if ($('#departureDate').datepicker('getDate') == null) {
                    jQuery('#departureDate').datepicker('show');
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('change', function(input, inst) {
        to.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#arrivalDate').datepicker('getDate'));
    });

    to = $('#departureDate').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($('#departureDate').outerWidth());
            }, 0);
        },
        onClose: function() {
            if ($('#departureDate').datepicker('getDate') != null) {
                if ($('#arrivalDate').datepicker('getDate') == null) {
                    jQuery('#arrivalDate').datepicker('show');
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('change', function(input, inst) {
        from.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#departureDate').datepicker('getDate'));
    });
    
    $('div.ui-datepicker').on('click', function() {
        $(this).outerWidth($('#arrivalDate').outerWidth());
    });
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="box"><input id="arrivalDate" type="text" /></div>
<div class="box"><input id="departureDate" type="text" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [jquery-ui.js](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js) file, I needed to change

```
// inst.dpDiv.removeClass( "ui-datepicker-multi-2 ui-datepicker-multi-3 ui-datepicker-multi-4" ).width( "" );
```

to

```
inst.dpDiv.removeClass( "ui-datepicker-multi-2 ui-datepicker-multi-3 ui-datepicker-multi-4" );
```